# I want to write a macro on Microsoft VBA in excel to do selection based on priority of the data in the columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data in Column S, the first letter of these data is one of the following: D, T, S, M
I want to write a code on Microsoft VBA in excel to extract the data of only 2 rows of these to the column M
The selected 2 rows should be on priority basis, having the highest priority for D then T then S then M

I wrote a code that I got from ChatGPT (see below).
The code does everything right except for the priority part, it always selects the data based on their order not priority. For instance, if I have them in the order T, M, S, D, it will select T and M because they came first, while it should select D and T respectively.

```vb
Sub Sage_Data_Extraction()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    ' Set the worksheet (change Sheet1 to the name of your sheet)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' Delete columns T, U, V, W
    ws.Columns("T:W").Delete

    ' Find the last row with data in column S
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each cell in column S (starting from S2)
    For Each cell In ws.Range("S2:S" & lastRow)
        ' Delete "." in the cell value
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, ".", "")

        ' Erase anything after the 5th character
        If Len(cell.Value) > 5 Then
            cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 5)
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Loop through each cell in column T (starting from T1)
    For Each cell In ws.Range("T1:T" & lastRow)
        ' Delete any characters before "856A"
        Dim position856A As Long
        position856A = InStr(1, cell.Value, "856A")
        If position856A > 0 Then
            cell.Value = Mid(cell.Value, position856A)
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Loop through each cell in column S (starting from S2)
    For Each cell In ws.Range("S2:S" & lastRow)
        Dim destRow As Long
        destRow = cell.Row ' Calculate destination row (4 or 5)

        If destRow >= 4 And destRow <= 5 Then
            Select Case UCase(Left(cell.Value, 1))
                Case "D"
                    ' Copy values from Columns S, U, and X to Columns M, N, and O
                    ws.Cells(destRow, "M").Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "S").Value
                    ws.Cells(destRow, "N").Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "U").Value
                    
                    ' Check if Column V contains "EUR" and multiply the value in Column N by 1.1
                    If InStr(1, UCase(ws.Cells(cell.Row, "V").Value), "EUR") > 0 Then
                        ws.Cells(destRow, "N").Value = ws.Cells(destRow, "N").Value * 1.1
                    End If
                    
                    ws.Cells(destRow, "O").Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "X").Value
                
                Case "T"
                    ' Copy values from Columns S, U, and X to Columns M, N, and O if the current value in M is not "D"
                    If UCase(ws.Cells(destRow, "M").Value) <> "D" Then
                        ws.Cells(destRow, "M").Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "S").Value
                        ws.Cells(destRow, "N").Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "U").Value
                        
                        ' Check if Column V contains "EUR" and multiply the value in Column N by 1.1
                        If InStr(1, UCase(ws.Cells(cell.Row, "V").Value), "EUR") > 0 Then
                            ws.Cells(destRow, "N").Value = ws.Cells(destRow, "N").Value * 1.1
                        End If
                        
                        ws.Cells(destRow, "O").Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "X").Value
                    End If
                
                Case "S"
                    ' Copy values from Columns S, U, and X to Columns M, N, and O if the current value in M is neither "D" nor "T"
                    If UCase(ws.Cells(destRow, "M").Value) <> "D" And UCase(ws.Cells(destRow, "M").Value) <> "T" Then
                        ws.Cells(destRow, "M").Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "S").Value
                        ws.Cells(destRow, "N").Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "U").Value
                        
                        ' Check if Column V contains "EUR" and multiply the value in Column N by 1.1
                        If InStr(1, UCase(ws.Cells(cell.Row, "V").Value), "EUR") > 0 Then
                            ws.Cells(destRow, "N").Value = ws.Cells(destRow, "N").Value * 1.1
                        End If
                        
                        ws.Cells(destRow, "O").Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "X").Value
                    End If
                
                Case "M"
                    ' Copy values from Columns S, U, and X to Columns M, N, and O if the current value in M is neither "D", "T", nor "S"
                    If UCase(ws.Cells(destRow, "M").Value) <> "D" And UCase(ws.Cells(destRow, "M").Value) <> "T" And UCase(ws.Cells(destRow, "M").Value) <> "S" Then
                        ws.Cells(destRow, "M").Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "S").Value
                        ws.Cells(destRow, "N").Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "U").Value
                        
                        ' Check if Column V contains "EUR" and multiply the value in Column N by 1.1
                        If InStr(1, UCase(ws.Cells(cell.Row, "V").Value), "EUR") > 0 Then
                            ws.Cells(destRow, "N").Value = ws.Cells(destRow, "N").Value * 1.1
                        End If
                        
                        ws.Cells(destRow, "O").Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, "X").Value
                    End If
            End Select
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

[Example of set of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meC0m.png)

Ideally the code should give me the below result

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbaG8.png)

But what actually happens is that it only takes the row of DDC23 and MDC23.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use a Dictionary object to keep row# in the expected priority order

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Sage_Data_Extraction()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In ws.Range("S2:S" & lastRow)
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, ".", "")
        If Len(cell.Value) > 5 Then
            cell.Value = Left(cell.Value, 5)
        End If
    Next cell
    For Each cell In ws.Range("T1:T" & lastRow)
        Dim position856A As Long
        position856A = InStr(1, cell.Value, "856A")
        If position856A > 0 Then
            cell.Value = Mid(cell.Value, position856A)
        End If
    Next cell
    ' ** change start here ** '
    Dim objDic As Object, sKey As String, vKey, vRow, destRow As Long
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Initial Dict object
    For Each vKey In Split("D T S M")  ' priority form high to low
        objDic(vKey) = ""
    Next
    ' Collect row# for each letter
    ' eg. objDic("D") = "5,8" means cells S5 and S8 start with D
    For Each cell In ws.Range("S2:S" & lastRow)
        sKey = UCase(Left(cell.Value, 1))
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & "," & CStr(cell.Row)
        End If
    Next
    destRow = 4
    ' Loop through each letter to populate the cells
    For Each vKey In objDic.Keys
        sKey = objDic(vKey)
        If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
            For Each vRow In Split(Mid(sKey, 2), ",")
                ws.Cells(destRow, "M").Value = ws.Range("S" & vRow).Value
                With ws.Cells(destRow, "N")
                    If Len(ws.Range("U" & vRow).Value)=0 Then
                        .Value = 0
                    Else
                        .Value = Split(ws.Range("U" & vRow).Value, " ")(0) * 1
                    End If
                    If InStr(1, ws.Range("V" & vRow).Value, "EUR", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        .Value = .Value * 1.1
                    End If
                End With
                ws.Cells(destRow, "O").Value = ws.Range("W" & vRow).Value
                destRow = destRow + 1
                If destRow > 5 Then Exit For ' Exit after found two rows
            Next
        End If
        If destRow > 5 Then Exit For
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I copied the above code to VBA but it didn't have any effect.
Could you please clarify if there is anything specific I should do?
I'm not very good with programming, so I might not be able to rectify errors or find them on my own.

Comment: Maybe try specifying what "didn't have any effect" means: i.e. you ran the code but nothing happened? You ran the code but the priority isn't working like before? You got an error? @MohamedElmisky

Comment: @MohamedElmisky please edit your post to show sample data and expected result. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Notus_Panda when I ran the code absolutely nothing happened. Not even the previous functions worked.

Comment: @taller I have edited the original post with an example of the data and expected result

Comment: @MohamedElmisky [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: @MohamedElmisky I've updated the code. Pls try again. I remove `ws.Columns("T:W").Delete`. It clears the source data.

Comment: @taller the line you removed is not really related to the function i'm looking for.
I'll try to explain this further.
I have some data extracted from a server (in the form of a screenshot) and pasted into excel using the "picture from clipboard" function (where excel uses OCR to convert the image into text).
Then I run the macro to do 2 main functions:
1. To clear out unnecessary data (which one of them is the line you removed)
2. To extract the data that I want into another column (which is the part that is not working properly)

Comment: To be more specific, everything is fine until *change start here*. After that the code doesn't do what I want it to do

Comment: Have you tried the revised code? The changes are more than just remove a line. I've tested it to get `Expected result` w/o any issures.

Comment: I tried it and I'm getting an error at the line:
.Value = Split(ws.Range("U" & vRow).Value, " ")(0) * 1

Comment: If the cell on Col U is blank, `Split` raises error. I've updated the code to fix it. Please try again.